Unable to create an Organization in Github
What I have done:
I created a new free user account on github and then I tried to create a new organization in Github by following the docs
https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/collaborating-with-groups-in-organizations/creating-a-new-organization-from-scratch
What's the issue?
The New Organization button is not showing up as per step No. 3. Can we not create an Organization on a free plan anymore?

What I expect?
I was hoping to create a new organization on my free plan, add my team members and later, once I've trained everyone, go for a paid plan.
